# Help on Differential Equation boundary conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I have the differential equation:

$\ x^2\ \frac{\ d^2 y}{\ d x^2} +2x\frac{\ d y}{\ d x} -6y=12$

This can be reduced to

$\ \frac{\ d^2 y}{\ d t^2} +\frac{\ d y}{\ d t} -6y=12$ [when x>0]

I have found the general solution to be:

y = $\ \frac{\ A}{\ x^3} +B\ x^2 -2$

I'm now having an issue with the boundary conditions to find a particular solution. The question is "Find the particular solution which satisfies the boundary condition y=3 when x=1, and for which y remains bounded as x tends to infinity". I get the bit to do with y(1)=3, but how do I go about dealing with the part about y remaining bounded as x tends to infinity? I'm sure it's probably really simple and I'm just being dumb but any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Based on your general solution you can choose $A$ and $B$ so that $\lim_{x\to\infty}y(x)$ exists and is finite.

Comment: @BindersFull so I would have to choose B to be zero, correct? Seeing as the first term is going to tend towards 0 and the second term is going to tend towards infinity?

Comment: Try it out. If $B = 0$ then no matter how you've chosen $A$ you'll get $\lim_{x\to\infty}y(x) = -2$. Does this agree with what it means for $y$ to be bounded as $x\to\infty$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the general solution you've obtained (It is correct, by the way):
$$y(x)=\frac{A}{x^3}+Bx^2-2$$
Note that $x^2 \to \infty$ as $x\to \infty$ and that $\frac{1}{x^3}\to 0$ as $x\to \infty$. Thus, if $B \neq 0$ for any $A\in \mathbb{R}$, then $y(x)\to \pm \infty$ as $x\to \infty$. The sign depends on whether $B$ is negative or positive. $y(x)\to \pm \infty$ does not satisfy the condition:

> For which $y$ remains **bounded** as $x\to \infty$.

This is because $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} y(x)$ must exist and must be finite for that condition to satisfy. The only way for $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} y(x)$ to be finite is when $B=0$. Thus, you now have:
$$y(x)=\frac{A}{x^3}-2$$
You should now be able to find $A$ from the condition $y(1)=3$.

---

To visualize your solution better, try moving the sliders $A$ and $B$ on [this graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/7sdhze6k1s) produced with Desmos Graphing Calculator.